# A basic confusion related to probability (Explanation needed)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume $X$ is a random variable which can only take non-negative values (that is its pdf is defined only over non-negative values). Which one of the following is true (and why?) $$P\left(-cX<g\right)=1$$ or $$P\left(X<-\frac{g}{c}\right)=0$$ where $c$ and $g$ are positive real values.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Just looking at the problem I found both of them to be true. Just as answered by angryavian below. But there can be only one of them which is true. I just looked at the problem and stuck. I do not where to start from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(-cX<g) = P(X>-g/c)=1$$
is true because $X$ is nonnegative.

$$P(X<-g/c)=0$$
is also true because $X$ is nonnegative.